# Another ACT question

Tags: pronouns

The following question appears in an official ACT study guide:

After much deliberation, Waiolo told Miguel that he would be able to drive (him, Miguel) to work on Saturday.

Solution: Miguel. In order to avoid ambiguity, restate the appropriate antecedent.

I disagree and would choose him. The whole point of pronouns is to avoid repetitious antecedents! Waiolo told Miguel – and only Miguel – he would drive him. Furthermore, "him" in its current form cannot refer to Waiolo (it would have to be himself). There's no ambiguity here; it's a bad question. On the other hand, the following question could refer to cleaning the living room or the furniture:

It’s best to take the furniture out of the living room in order to clean (it, the furniture).

Solution: The furniture. In order to avoid ambiguity between whether the living room or the furniture’s cleaning is discussed, use an expressed noun phrase instead of a pronoun.

Comment: If I tell you that you will drive me to work tomorrow, then oerkelens tells user27343 that he will drive him to work, but _him_ refers to oerkelens.

Comment: I'll delete the other question. This is a better forum for it.

Comment: I wasn't aware this forum existed at the time.

Comment: I asked for it to be migrated here.

Comment: Exam questions may be off topic.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that. Either way, Jason answered my question and I thank him for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *purpose* of the exercise is to remove ambiguity, then *Miguel* must be used.

> After much deliberation, Waiolo told Miguel that **he** would be able to drive **him** to work on Saturday.

Because of the use of **he**, this sentence has two possible interpretations:

1. After much deliberation, Waiolo told Miguel that **Waiolo [he]** would be able to drive **Miguel [him]** to work on Saturday.
2. After much deliberation, Waiolo told Miguel that **Miguel [he]** would be able to drive **Waiolo [him]** to work on Saturday.

The only way to remove the ambiguity of who **he** in the first part of the sentence is referring to is by giving a specific name in the second part of the sentence.

Using **Miguel** in the second part of the sentence *forces* **he** in the first part of the sentence to refer to Waiolo.

> After much deliberation, Waiolo told Miguel that he would be able to drive Miguel to work on Saturday.

Yes, this doesn't sound natural. But the point of the exercise isn't to make it sound natural. As stated, the purpose is to avoid ambiguity. This is the only version that does that.

Choosing to ignore the instructions, while possibly resulting in a better sentence, is the wrong answer nonetheless.

---

Of course, the best option (which is not available) is to rephrase the sentence altogether:

> After much deliberation, Waiolo offered to drive Miguel to work on Saturday.

Comment: It's as if Waiolo is doing Miguel a favor by letting Miguel drive him to work, which sounds ridiculous, but I think you're right. The second "Miguel" must be added to avoid ambiguity. Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. For the first question, because it's not "himself", it would not grammatically refer to Waiolo.

Further, "He told Miguel he would drive Miguel to work" is actually fairly ambiguous, and in violation of reported speech. Because we're reporting what was probably something like "I will drive **you** to work", the natural way to report the second-person pronoun is to convert it to a third-person pronoun. Using "Miguel" twice actually makes me think that there might be a *second* person named Miguel, because why else would you repeat it so unnaturally?

So yes, your answer is the most natural way to say it. That's a bad question (which sadly often exist on tests).

For the second question, the best answer is to just rephrase the entire sentence. It is rather unnatural to repeat "furniture", but "it" is very unclear. If it were me, I would just change the entire sentence, which sadly isn't an option for the test question.

So I guess in the end, for the sake of the test, I guess you have to ignore how English is actually used in order to maximize technical precision.

Comment: The point of the exercise/lesson is to demonstrate how pronouns relate to their antecedents with the goal of avoiding ambiguity. In the second question, if you don't repeat furniture – even though it's unnatural – it sounds like you could be cleaning the living room. However, I still don't think repeating Miguel was necessary.

Comment: I understand the goal of the lesson, however my point is that it's not a test of *English* but rather clarity, and it's a poor test of clarity to give an unclear sentence, and choose the least unclear word to insert. In the case of the furniture, for example, I would say, "In order to clean the furniture, it’s best to take it out of the living room." So my point is just that the test question is poorly designed, requiring a choice between two bad options.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Some of the answers I received on the other forum were focused on the repetition, which was very common in the answer sets for this exercise.

Comment: No problem. It's true that English speakers hate repetition, especially names. That's a big part of what makes it so unnatural. And that unnatural feeling is part of what makes it a bad question. You have to choose between ambiguity, and bad writing. 9 times out of 10, natives speakers will choose the former, and then possibly have to explain themselves later.